# How do I search the company's tickers that are mentioned from reddit wallstreetbets platform?

Tags: python, database, api, reddit

I want to use the code below, but right now for searching the company's ticker name, I could only search it by searching the symbol"$". Is there any way I can search the name without the "$"? The full python code is shown below:

```
from psaw import PushshiftAPI 
import config
import datetime 
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

connection = psycopg2.connect(host=config.DB_HOST, database=config.DB_NAME, user=config.DB_USER, password=config.DB_PASS)

cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM stock
""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

stocks = {}
for row in rows:
    stocks['$' + row['symbol']] = row ['id']

api = PushshiftAPI()

start_time  = int(datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 19).timestamp())

submissions = api.search_submissions(after=start_time,
                            subreddit='wallstreetbets',
                            filter=['url','author', 'title', 'subreddit'],)

for submission in submissions:
    words = submission.title.split()
    cashtags = list(set(filter(lambda word: word.lower().startswith('$'), words)))

    if len(cashtags) > 0:
        #print(cashtags)
        #print(submission.created_utc)
        #print()
        #print(submission.url)

        for cashtag in cashtags:
            submitted_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(submission.created_utc).isoformat()

            try:
                cursor.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO mention (dt, stock_id,message,source,url)
                    VALUES (%s, %s. %s, 'wallstreetbets', %s)
                """, (submitted_time, stocks[cashtag], submission.title, submission.url))
            
                connection.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                connection.rollback()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the python code you have this code at the beginning

```py
for row in rows:
    stocks['$' + row['symbol']] = row ['id']
```

This code prefixes all row names with "$"

And later you have this line in your code

```py
cashtags = list(set(filter(lambda word: word.lower().startswith('$'), words)))
```

This line will filter the cashtags by words that start with a $

The `startsWith('$')` part is responsible for checking if a word starts with a $.

If you want to search without the $ just remove that part

```py
cashtags = list(set(filter(lambda word: word.lower(), words)))
```

I think the original author of the code searched only on the words prefixed with a $, because he prefixes all the row names with a $ at the start of the function. So the code is faster if you only want to search by row names.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I filter the words narrowed to only uppercase Letter?

Comment: At least put some effort in it. Like what have you tried. This is a platform to help with code not a free coding service yo